# flash drive available space lower than expected with ext4

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive, formatting, ext4

I recently formatted a 256G flash drive with *ext4* on debian. Afterwards I set the reserved disk space to 0 via `tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sdb1`.
However when I call `df -h` the available space shows only 229G. With a 256G capacity I would expect it to be around 238G. The default file system was vfat which showed the capacity correctly as around 238G.

Did I miss something here?

Comment: Is it helpful to set journaling off explicitly with `tune2fs -O "^has_journal" /dev/sb1` ?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik After applying that command it now shows 230G instead of 229G.